# Android 2.2 equivalent of Java Swing's SwingWorker Class?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, swingworker

I am new to Android and may target platform is 2.2.
If I'm not mistaken, android is multi-threaded ready.
I am wondering of the equivalent of SwingWorker class.

Guys, would you guide me on the right direction on how to dealt with multi-threading application using Android 2.2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at `AsyncTask` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

There's even more detailed information available here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/processes-and-threads.html